# Verilog Error: Assignment to separate vector index (Dimensional error)

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

```
 assign flag_temp[3:0]  = ((op_dec == 5'b00000) ? flag_temp[3:0] : 
//ADD
 ((op_dec == 5'b00001) ? flag_temp[3:0] :                            
//SUB
((op_dec == 5'b00010) ? flag_temp[1], flag_temp[3], flag_temp[0] = 1'b0, flag_temp[2] = 1'b0 :  
//MOV    
Status bits :- flag_ex[0] = carry; flag_ex[1] = zero;
flag_ex[2] = overflow; flag_ex[3] = parity;
```

I have to reset carry and overflow flag but it shows syntax and dimensional error.

Answer (score 0):

some syntax in the code can to be fixed . You can group a set of signals via the { } operator .

```
 wire [3:0] flag_temp;
 assign flag_temp [3:0]  = (op_dec == 5'b00000) ? flag_temp[3:0] :
                (op_dec == 5'b00001) ? flag_temp[3:0] :
                (op_dec == 5'b00010) ? {flag_temp[1], flag_temp[3], flag_temp[0]} : {flag_temp[2]} ;
```

There are unmatched braces. two opening (( but only one closing ). 
Also there assignments , flag_temp[0] = 1'b0 in the assign statement , It beats the purpose of the assign itself.
Also flag_temp is being assigned itself , there is no external value assigned to it. This will result in a the flag_temp remaining "x" always.

The intention the code is not very clear to me so cannot make a more meaningful suggestion.

---

Updated Code  - 
Below is the sample code which does some data model based operation . the rest of the operators can be added on similar lines.

For signals which do now change for a specific operation the values are looped back and for the operations which change the specific flags are added to the concatenation "{}" operator.
last is the default were the original value is retained .

```
reg  [3:0] x ;
reg  [3:0] y;
wire  [3:0] sum;
wire carry_i = 1 ; // driven to 1 for example 
wire zero ;
assign {carr_o,sum} = x+y+carry_i ;

assign flag_ex[3:0] =  (op_dec == 5'b00000) ? { flag_ex[3],flag_ex[2],flag_ex[1],carr_o} : // ADD
                         (op_dec == 5'b00001) ? { flag_ex[3],flag_ex[2],flag_ex[1],carr_o}: // SUB
                         (op_dec == 5'b00010) ? { flag_ex[3],flag_ex[2],zero,flag_ex[0]}:  // MOV
                        flag_ex[3:0]; //default
```

Comment: Its the code for a processor and I am adding flags (carry, overflow, zero and parity), and it is compulsory to use data flow modelling. The intention is to reset the carry and overflow flag while parity and zero will be affected by (for eg) A&B operation.

Comment: updated the code to use a simple data flow modeling example